# Corechart for graphs and Columnchart for functions - At the same time?

Tags: google-visualization

I´ve a bunch of graphs that works perfectly with Corechart package but i´ve a function to calculate elevation in Google Maps that uses Columnchart package and this one doesnt work well when loading Corechart. If i load Columnchart package, the function works ok but i cant manage to set the graphs straight. Loading both packages at the same time doesnt produce good results (neither is recommended by Google).

Columnchart loaded: Elevation ok, Graphs not ok.
http://preview.tinyurl.com/mf9g9fq

Corechart loaded: Elevation not ok, Graphs ok.
http://preview.tinyurl.com/m59p4wf

I suppose the only way to resolve this is to edit how i build the charts or how the function "Elevation" is build..but after many hours i cant manage to get both working ok.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Load the "corechart" package and set the vAxis.minValue to 0 to make the elevations correct.  Also, "width" is not a valid suboption of hAxis.  If you intend to make the chart 200px wide, you need to set the width as its own option:

```
var options = {
    width: 200,
    hAxis: {
        title: 'Total: ' + sum + '. Avg.: ' + avg,
        titleTextStyle: {
            color: 'red'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        position: 'none'
    },
    vAxis: {
        minValue: 0
    }
};
```

Also, you are drawing the chart from the "onload" event of the `<body>`, which is a no-no.  You need to use a callback handler from the google loader to draw the chart, otherwise you may experience problems with the rendered chart (like not having any hAxis labels, as is the case when I view the chart).  Remove the `zz();` call from `initialize` and add it as a callback in the loader:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"], callback: zz});
```